# React-slick - Hide dots conditionally in multiple items carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm new to react, so maybe this question is a bit basic.
I have a multiple items carousel. Dots is currently set to true, but when it is loaded dynamically with 4 slides and the settings are:

slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 4,
The dot is still displayed for tablets (max-width: 768px)... The point is that I would like to hide it.

Is there a way to add a condition so when the slide count is 4 , for responsive width 768px to hide the dot?

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/fauslg/pen/wXmWxL

`this.settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      arrows: false,
      responsive:`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code in your SliderComponent and add:

```
    constructor(props){
.....
        let {settings} = this.props;

            for(let i = 0; i<settings.response.length();i++)

    {

    if(response[i].breakpoint == 768 && 

    response[i].settings.slidesToShow==4){

    settings.dots= false;

    break;

    }

    }


            ......
            .....
            }
```

If the response array is always of the same structure(you know that width 768 is the second entry always):

```
    constructor(props){
.......
            let {settings} = this.props;
        settings.dots= (
      response[1].settings.slidesToShow==4)? false : true;
        ....}
```